# is this a safe fix for angularjs bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've just encountered this bug :

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5201

> forEach function throws this error at line 295 of angular 1.2.3 version. Trace leads to the forEach(element.attributes, ... ) call of angularInit function at line 1248.
>
> The problem is that in IE8 the element.attributes property is instace of [object DispHTMLAttributeCollection] which doesn't support hasOwnPropertyMethod hence the exception.
>
> Seems that the issue does not occur in other IE versions.

I'm using AngularJS v1.2.5 but receiving same issue.

I'm considering using [this fix](https://github.com/pjparra/angular.js/commit/8c2ed24412620d68a760cfab70e4dc27a49b9e91):

```
if (key != 'prototype' && key != 'length' && key != 'name' && (obj.hasOwnProperty && obj.hasOwnProperty(key) || Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key))) {
```

instead of

```
if (key != 'prototype' && key != 'length' && key != 'name' && obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
```

Is this a safe fix ? I don't understand why `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` is added to AND condition and what `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)` achieves ?

Is `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)` equivalent to `obj.hasOwnProperty` ?